# Why does this python code exhibit weird scoping rules

Tags: python, list-comprehension, scoping, dictionary-comprehension

I'm running on Python 2.7.8 (Anaconda Distribution) and this code fails. This looks like a bug in the Python implementation, but am I missing anything?

```
class C:
    x = {2 : 1}
    y = {w for w in x if x[w]==1}
```

Running this code gives the following error message:

> NameError: global name 'x' is not defined

The error message also seems wrong to me.

Note that the following two very similar pieces of code do work with no problems:

```
# this works fine:
class C:
    x = {2 : 1}
    y = [w for w in x if x[w]==1]


# this works fine too:
x = {2 : 1}
y = {w for w in x if x[w]==1}
```

Comment: how are you running it? There is no error in what you have provided

Comment: It fails on the interactive interpreter and also in an ipython notebook

Comment: Are you trying to create a new set based on a specific filtering criterion?

Comment: it works fine for me. After defining the class, I run `foo = C(); print foo.x; print foo.y`

Comment: Works for me, too, when creating the class, and I can execute the same code @MattDMo did with success. That's with `python` 2.7.3. However, I also tried `ipython` 0.12 and it failed as stated.

Comment: ok I can replicate in ipython when creating the class using python 2.7.6 and 3.4.2

Comment: ok, I think it's settled: the link @PascalBugnion gives claims it's a bug by design, which happens because of weird scoping rules related to set comprehensions. Apparently it's because set comprehensions were backported to Python 2.7, and the way to solve it is just to upgrade to version 3.0, or try to not use set comprehensions when they vreak like this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry for wasting everyone's time!

Comment: @mobiusdumpling: see the dupe I used to close your question, there are other ways.

Comment: set([w for w in x if x[w]==1]) will work. but you already know that :) replicated in Ipython (2.7)

Comment: Update to my other comment - the original code worked for me with 2.7.9 in Windows, but when I ran it with 2.7.8 in Linux, I got the same error. Interesting...

Comment: @MartijnPieters, the dupe answer suggests this is a bug fixed in python 3 but I can replicate using python 3.4.2 in ipython

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: the fact that list comprehensions *don't* have a scope was the bug. Using a list comprehension will produce the same behaviour as set and dictionary comprehensions (and generator expressions) in Python 3. The behaviour is *by design*.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: please do read the whole answer carefully.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, but why does the code work using pycharm and work for some people on windows and not on linux?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Testing errors. Usually because they have a preexisting global.

Comment: @MattDMo: Now start a fresh session where you do **not** have a preexisting global `x`. The set comprehension looks for a global, not the name in the class scope (which is not a scope as far as nesting is concerned). If it worked anyway, you had a global named `x` already.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yep.

Comment: @Martijn you're right. I had tested the `x = {2 : 1}; y = {w for w in x if x[w]==1}` code in my session before defining the class. I restarted my session, and got the error.